# Other APIs are fetching normal, but some APIs takes time 2-5 minutes to get response, jquery Ajax fetches in milli seconds same APIs

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-requests

I need to integrate ShipStation with my Python web app. ShipStation APIs are executing very slower by python requests package, taking time about 2-5 minutes. I also tried to fetch more heavier APIs which are fetching normally.

I tested Shipstation APIs using jQuery Ajax, Postman and it's taking time in milliseconds, or 1-2seconds. What's wrong with requests library. Please help me. Samples:

**python example -- taking minutes 2-5**

```
import requests

# request header
headers = { 'Authorization': '' }

# shipstaion carrier services listing api endpoint
list_services = 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/carriers/listservices?carrierCode=stamps_com'

# making get request
res = requests.get(list_services, headers=headers)

# results
print("services_list: ", res, " and type is: ", type(res))
```

**jQuery Ajax example taking milliseconds or 1-2 seconds:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    </body>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/carriers/listservices?carrierCode=stamps_com',
            headers: { 'Authorization': '' },
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response)
                    {

                        console.log(response);//does not print in the console
                    }

        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe server needs some `hearders`  in requests - ie. `user-agent`. I don't know what sends `Postman` but `AJAX` sends `User-Agent` like `Mozilla/5.0 ...` but `Python` sends `Python/3.7 ...` and some servers may have problem with this value.

Comment: I tested Python code (without `User-Agent` and with empty `Authorization`) and it takes only few seconds.